# How to add multiple NSStrings into an NSMutableArray at one index

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray

Probably a really dumb question but I'm having some trouble. Essentially I'm trying to take a first name and last name from text fields in the storyboard and store both values into one index of an array to call back at another time. Here's what I have:

> *//File.h*
>   @property NSString *firstName;
>   @property NSString *lastName;
>   - initWithFirstName: (NSString *) firstName lastName: (NSString *) lastName;

> *//File.m*
>   -(id) initWithFirstName: (NSString *) firstName lastName: (NSString *) lastName{
>   
>     self.firstName = firstName;
>   self.lastName = lastName;
>   return self;
>   }

> *//ViewController.h*
>   @property File *name;
>   @property NSMutableArray *array;

> *//ViewController.m*
>   [super viewDidLoad]
>   self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
>   self.name = [[File alloc] initWithFirstName: self.firstNameText.text lastName: self.lastNameText.text];
>   *//under the save button*
>   [self.array addObject:self.name];
>   *//under the restore button*
>   self.firstNameText.text = self.array[..?

That part (..?) is where I screw up. I can't go self.array[0].firstName because it doesn't exist. If I put array without an index the same thing happens. I know I must be messing up somewhere, maybe the firstName and lastName aren't even getting stored into the array at all.
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get using

```
self.firstNameText.text = ((File*)self.array[0]).firstName;
```

or

```
self.firstNameText.text = [[self.array objectAtIndex:0] firstName];
```

Your firstName and lastName are stored as Object in array, so you need to typecast it into object back to get it working :)

Answer (score 1):

//under the restore button

```
File *objFile=[self.array objectAtIndex:0];

self.firstNameText.text=objFile.firstName;
```